# Resize image based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I am using isotope.js in a wordpress theme. I want the user to upload a single image, and then select its shape.

The shape choices are square, long rectangle, and tall rectangle. I'd rather not have the user upload an additional image if they don't have to - and I'd rather use either CSS or Javascript/jQuery to handle the shaping process.

Is this even possible?

::edit:: this is in a responsive layout, so I can't use hard pixel sizes for heights or widths.

Comment: I think we need more context here. What happens after they select its shape? What is your end goal?

Comment: You can clip images to certain shapes using inline SVG with path clipping, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @ DA. The shape the user selects reflects the shape of the final image in the isotope.js grid. For example, if they upload a 1600x1200 image and they choose the 'long rectangle' option, then the image should crop/change into something like 800x300.